# How to get an alert when the build is Fixed using TFS2013 Build Server?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2013

It's easy to set up alerts for when the build fails (`Status = Failed`), but I'd like to be able get an alert when the build is fixed, too. (IE. An alert for the first 'Success' following a 'Failed' build.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a plugin or web service that records the last known state of a given build definition and then when it receives the current state transition from bad to good send an email saying the build is fixed.